# PAT Token creation via terraform - API version string must be in format

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform

I'm able to create PAT Token via Terraform with very simple way:

```
resource "restapi_object" "pat_token_ado_creation" {
  path = "/_apis/tokens/pats/pats?api-version=7.0-preview.1"
  data = jsonencode({
    displayName        = "PAT_${var.organisation}"
    scope = "vso.project_write"
    validTo = timeadd(timestamp(), "1h")
    allOrgs = false
  })
  id_attribute = "patToken/displayName"
  update_method = "PUT"
}
```

This works just fine BUT when I'm trying to destroy this token, I'm getting following error:

```
Error: unexpected response code '500': {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Invalid api version string: \"7.0-preview.1/PAT_CWF\". Api version string must be in the format: {Major}.{Minor}[-preview[.{ResourceVersion}]].","typeName":"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssInvalidApiResourceVersionException, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi","typeKey":"VssInvalidApiResourceVersionException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}
```

Comment: Which provider is this?

Comment: This is an issue in the provider. There are other RESTAPI providers you can use which may be more helpful.

Comment: Its this one: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/Mastercard/restapi/latest